# The three note danger idiom

Tags: soundtrack, sound-effects, origin

There is a three note idiom that has appeared in SEVERAL theatrical releases (comedies) recently that indicates danger.  I do not know the notes, but it goes "dum dum **DUM**", and the viewer knows instantly that the scene (or character) is dangerous. There are even sound effect videos of this idiom on YouTube, but they are very short on its etymology. Again, was this composed?  Does somebody own rights to this idiom?  If not, how did it enter popular culture?

A sample, accompanied by rich viewer commentary, is at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bW7Op86ox9g

Comment: I think  it came it by way of Perry Mason. I'll do more research but it's a show like that. Maybe Peter Gunn...

Comment: If there are *YouTube* videos of this, can you maybe add a link to one of those for clarity?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson, edited with link

Comment: It comes from the WW2 propaganda news videos (all news - whenever there was danger afoot)

Comment: It's actually called: "Shock Horror" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhgFDo7XPu0

Comment: Similar thread: http://askville.amazon.com/dramatic-three-note-musical-sting-bump-bummmmm/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=1393675

Comment: Dick Walter appears to be the recognised "composer": http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0910011/

Answer (score 2):

It's actually called: "Shock Horror".

It has been credited to  Dick Walter: http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0910011

I stated in a comment that it had been used during wartime (BBC/ABC/NBC) as a danger signal, much as the first couple of bars of Beethoven 5th "(morse code) V for victory" music however this was mistaken.